# Перестановка символов с помощью рекурсии

Tags: java

Имеется массив `char ['a','b','c']` нужно найти все возможные варианты с помощью рекурсии. Код я примерно написал но проблема в том что не знаю когда выходить из рекурсии.

Код

```
public static char[] shift(char[] tabs, int i) {
    //if(i+1>tabs.length)return tabs;
    if (i + 1 == tabs.length) return shift(tabs, 0);
    char tmp;
    tmp = tabs[i];
    tabs[i] = tabs[i + 1];
    tabs[i + 1] = tmp;

    for (int j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++)
    System.out.print(tabs[j] + " ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    return shift(tabs, i + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] tab = {
        'a', 'b', 'c'
    };
    shift(tab, 0);
}
```

Comment: количество вариантов посчитайте. для любого `N` кажется будет `N!` для `3` это `3! = 3*2*1 = 6`

Comment: А зачем вообще рекурсия? Это и без неё нормально делается. В С++ есть функция даже next_permutaion() , в Java не помню.

Comment: @pavel  задание нынче такие по теми рекурсия.

Comment: С учебными заданиями не к нам, а к вашему лектору. Мы здесь не бесплатный обучающий семинар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> спасибо pavel за идею

*Next permutation* идея проста, нужно найти следуюшее из переборов. Рассмотрим  с примером

В левой части до и а правой после *Next permutation*

```
1,2,3 → 1,3,2
3,2,1 → 1,2,3
1,1,5 → 1,5,1
```

Анализ

Как это решить:
1) проходим с право на лево, находим первый элемент который меньше предыдушего.

```
4 5 6 3 2 1 
  |
  p
```

2) проходим с право на лево, находим первый элемент который больше p.

```
4 5 6 3 2 1 
    |
    q
```

3) меняем p и q

```
4 5 6 3 2 1 
swap
4 6 5 3 2 1
```

4) меняем местами элементы  [p+1, nums.length]

```
4 6 1 2 3 5
```

Код на `Java`

```
public void nextPermutation(int[] nums) {
    if(nums == null || nums.length<2)
        return;

    int p=0;            
    for(int i=nums.length-2; i>=0; i--){
        if(nums[i]<nums[i+1]){
            p=i;
            break;
        }    
    }

    int q = 0;
    for(int i=nums.length-1; i>p; i--){
        if(nums[i]> nums[p]){
            q=i;
            break;
        }    
    }

    if(p==0 && q==0){
        reverse(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
        return;
    }

    int temp=nums[p];
    nums[p]=nums[q];
    nums[q]=temp;

    if(p<nums.length-1){
        reverse(nums, p+1, nums.length-1);
    }
}

public void reverse(int[] nums, int left, int right){
    while(left<right){
        int temp = nums[left];
        nums[left]=nums[right];
        nums[right]=temp;
        left++;
        right--;
    }
}
```

[источник](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/06/leetcode-next-permutation-java/)

Comment: ну раз пошла такая пьянка , то с факториалом разве не проще ? просто преподаватель сказал та там 4 строки рекурсией , вот я и думаю как же 4 строки .

Comment: @user2420249 кому как. выбор за вами